# convert curl to python

Tags: python, curl

I wonder if it is possible to convert the following OpenFIGI API command into python:

```
curl -v -X POST 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'   \
     --header 'Content-Type: text/json'             \
     --data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'
```

I tried the following:

```
import requests
data = {["idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"]}
r=requests.post('https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping', headers={"Content-Type": "text/json"},data=data)
```

But r gets the value "Response [400]". According to the intro page https://www.openfigi.com/api#introduction, this identifies the scenario that     "The request body is not an array". I am really new to curl, any suggestion will help.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/ will convert your command for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First api expects array of objects, not an object with array ( that's even invalid json) so correct is this:

```
data = [{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]
```

Second - api expects json, so use json parameter, not data

```
r=requests.post('https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',
                headers={"Content-Type": "text/json"},
                json=data)
```